# Is it possible, to find hyper-links in PDF-Source-Text?

Tags: pdf

I am trying to find hyperlinks, which direct to other files on my pc, in PDF-Source-Text. 
I do not know, if this is even possible.
I need to make a feature which filters hyperlinks out of PDF-Code, so it can  show me the linked file in my Browser together with the main-PDF-file(obviousely again as PDF), so I can print them all together with Universal-Print(firefox-PlugIn).

kind regards,
Peter | Viman4s
Is it possible to find hyperlinks out of PDF-Source-Text?

Comment: What do you mean by *"PDF-Source-Text"*?

Comment: I mean the plain Text that shows up, whe you open a PDF in Text-Editor.

Comment: Whether you see anything usable in a text editor, depends on the compression used in the pdf. If object streams are used, you'll probably find nothing of use.